# Cannot get getColumn and getRow methods to return any values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Google apps script (and javascript for that matter).

In the code below I keep getting "No logs found. Use Logger API to add logs to your project.", tried adding an "event" variable to the onEdit() trigger with no avail.

```
function onEdit() {
  var test =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test");
  var activeCell = test.getActiveCell();
  var col = activeCell.getColumn();
  var row = activeCell.getRow();
  Logger.Log(col);
  Logger.Log(row);   
    if(col == 1 && row == 1) {
     var testVar = 1;
     Logger.log(testVar);   
 } 
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: How about modifying from ``Logger.Log`` to ``Logger.log``?

Comment: Thanks so much Tanaike, beginners mistake :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with this to learn more about the event object.  It really has a lot of information in it right of out the box.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='test'){return;}//keeps other pages from affecting the performance of the onEdit function
  var activeCell = e.range;//typically e.range is one cell
  var col = e.range.columnStart;//there's also a columnEnd
  var row = e.range.rowStart;//there's also a rowEnd
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));//take a look at this and see what else is there
  Logger.Log(col);
  Logger.Log(row);   
  if(col == 1 && row == 1 && e.range.getSheet().getName()=='test') {
    var testVar = 1;
    Logger.log(testVar);   
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Cooper, I'll give it a try!